# advantage of euclidean distance for classification

Tags: classification, distance-functions, k-nearest-neighbour, euclidean

Has euclidean distance any advantage in compare to another distance based methods like Manhatan distance or Maximum difference metric?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends a lot on your use-case.

- If you're working in a continuous space where all dimensions are properly scaled and relevant, then Euclidean is going to be a great choice for distance function.
- If you have a space filled with exclusively countable dimensions, then Manhattan distance will make sense.

Unfortunately, there are rarely clear-cut cases. The best approach is to experiment with a variety of distance functions and see what works best for your data.